# Чтение из файла .txt с разделителями

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Есть файл 123.txt в котором (Имя, пол, рост):

```
Dima, M, 182
Katya, F, 167
Petr, M, 165
Andrey, M, 177
Ira, F, 179
```

Не знаю как сделать запятую разделителем слов, чтобы, например, в 1-ой строке

```
Dima, M, 182
```

"Dima" - Значение переменной "Name"

"M" - Значение переменной "Sex"

"182" - Значение переменной "Height"

У меня всё мешается в кучу и переменная "Name" принимает значение "Dima, M, 182"

Как сделать, чтобы строка разбивалась на несколько переменных?

Comment: Приведите пример кода, как вы пытались сделать.

Comment: Предполагаю, что Вы считываете построчно в переменную. Что-то в стиле `writeln(fileName, name)`. Тогда, можно найти первое вхождение запятой в строку, и подстрока от 1го символа до запятой и будет именем. Аналогично рассуждая, можно получить остальные параметры

Comment: @lDrakonl, вот и я так думаю. Но я не знаю как всё это написать на паскале со вхождениями и прочим.

Comment: @Ant1mas: У вас таки pascal или delphi? Какая версия?

Comment: Тут неплохо расписаны функции работы со строками:http://mif.vspu.ru/books/pascal/string.html Посмотрите в сторону copy, pos. Их должно хватить. Постарайтесь задавать более конкретные вопросы. А то кажется, что Вы ждете, что за вас тут напишут всю программу.

Comment: @VladD, PascalABC.NET v2.2, сборка 842 (08.02.2015)

Comment: @Ant1mas: А, так вы можете использовать .NET? А `string.Split` + `int.Parse` не подходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.StrUtils.SplitString

```
list := SplitString(string, ', ');
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: но речь вроде о паскале, а не о делфи